# Tensorflow 2 XOR implementation

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am a tensorflow newbie and to start with I want to train XOR model giving 4 inputs having 2 values and learn 4 output having 1 value.
Here is what I am doing in TF 2

```
    model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=2, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation='softmax')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    history = model.fit(
        (tf.cast([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]], tf.float32), tf.cast([0,1,1,0], tf.float32)),
        epochs=4,
        steps_per_epoch=1,
        validation_data=(tf.cast([[0.7, 0.7]], tf.float32), tf.cast([0], tf.float32)),
        validation_steps=1
       )
```

Above code is giving error `IndexError: list index out of range`

Please help me with this and I want to understand how to come up with shapes to give to model.

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem with assigning your parameters in the fit function in:

```
history = model.fit(
    (tf.cast([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]], tf.float32), tf.cast([0,1,1,0], tf.float32)),
    epochs=4,
    steps_per_epoch=1,
    validation_data=(tf.cast([[0.7, 0.7]], tf.float32), tf.cast([0], tf.float32)),
    validation_steps=1)
```

Try and replace that line with this:

```
x_train = tf.cast([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]], tf.float32)
y_train = tf.cast([0,1,1,0], tf.float32)
x_test = tf.cast([[0.7, 0.7]], tf.float32)
y_test = tf.cast([0], tf.float32)
history = model.fit(
    x=x_train, y=y_train,
    epochs=4,
    steps_per_epoch=1,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    validation_steps=1
    )
```

And your issue should be solved.

PS: Just a suggestion, when you are doing binary classification, try to use sigmoid instead of a softmax, and respectively a BinaryCrossentropy loss instead of CategoricalCrossentropy. Good luck